# Node.js game server running multiple games at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am creating a game server in Node.js and I think I have a good server loop going with `setInterval()`.  However, the way I plan to make my game is having many small instances of games running at the same time, meaning having many different loops of `setInterval()` happening at once.

Can too many `setInterval()` running at the same time be problematic, and if so, is there a better way to structure my server?  e.g. attempting to run all instances of the game within one `setInterval()` loop?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please see : How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stack overflow is extremely helpful when you include your actual code.  We are not nearly as helpful when the questions are entirely theoretical.  And one main reason for that is because questions like yours are nearly always in the category of "it depends".  When it depends upon a lot of things, we need to see actual code to offer a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

With a purely theoretical question and no code or data included, the answer is yes.  It can certainly be possible to be running too many `setInterval()` calls at the same time.

As with most gaming, if your require some predictable timing of the `setInterval()` calls in order to maintain smooth game flow, then as you get more and more calls running, you start to lose the predictability for when they will run.  Because Javascript in node.js is a single threaded event-driven design, if two `setInterval()` calls are scheduled to happen at the same moment, one will run first and the other won't run until the first is done with its work.  How many you need to have before this becomes a noticeable issue depends entirely upon the circumstances of your code - how many you have, how long each one takes to execute and what your game's tolerance for slight delays in timing is.

Because of node.js single threaded nature, it is not great at having a single process that is trying to do lots of timing-sensitive things.  The typical way to work-around this is to use multiple node.js processes (often one per CPU core in your computer) so you get all the CPU cores involved.  There are even cases where you're trying to promote more fairness between actions that you may want to have more processes than you have CPU cores as this gives you some OS-driven time slicing between work going on in different node.js processes.

Since we don't know anything about your specifics, we can't say whether you would benefit from clustering (multiple node.js processes all running the same code and all sharing incoming load) or from using a separate node.js app for each N instances of the game where N is something you figure out by testing.  Probably you want a single game instance handled by one particular node instance so your model is more like the second option (N game instances per node.js instance), but that's just a guess since we have no specifics.

But as I said in my comment, because you've asked a purely theoretical question with no code and no data, all we can really do is answer hypothetically - there is no real world code or data to go by.